# Getting php to copy a folder to home directory of user

Tags: 16.04, apache2, php

I am using Nano Pi Neo using Ubuntu 16.04(Xenial) running Apache . I am trying to do a firware update in which I upload a zip file via web interface . A php script unzips the file which updates the root of Apache (/var/www) and copies a folder "scripts" to home directory of user pi(/home/pi) . I have given the ownership of the "/home/pi/scripts" to www-data but it still gives me the following error .

`cp: cannot stat '/home/pi/scripts/test document.txt': Permission denied .`

My code sample is here

```
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"],"/var/www/".$target_dir.$target_file)){
            //echo "The file ". basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])." has been uploaded.";
            $f=fopen('PASSWORD_DIR/password.txt','r');
            $line=fgets($f);
            fclose($f);
            $line=str_replace(array("\n","\r"),'',$line);
            exec("unzip -P ".$line." -o /var/www/uploads/ZIPPED_FILE.zip -d /var/www/uploads/",$output,$result);
            if($result==0){
            exec("cp -TRv /var/www/uploads/html/ /var/www/");
            exec("cp -TRv /var/www/uploads/scripts/ /home/pi/scripts");//THIS CAUSES AN ISSUE
            exec("cd /home/pi/scripts && make");
            exec("rm --interactive=never /var/www/uploads/ZIPPED_FILE.zip");
            exec("rm --interactive=never -r /var/www/uploads/html");
            exec("rm --interactive=never -r /var/www/uploads/scripts");
            echo("<script>alert('software has been installed')</script>");
            //echo("<script>window.history.go(-2)</script>");
            //$out=shell_exec("whoami");
            //echo $out;
            }
```

Comment: I think you need to add a slash `/` after "scripts"  `/home/pi/scripts/`

Comment: Doesn't do anything .

Comment: And what about the "test" folder. It is not mentioned in the script.

Comment: It is not a folder. "test document.txt" is a file in scripts directory .

Comment: Better rename it to test_document.txt

Comment: Sadly , that doesn't work too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95489/discussion-between-kishore-saldanha-and-john-ronald).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question , the solution was to give write permissions to the directory scripts using

`chmod g+rx /home/pi/scripts` . If that doesn't work you can create a shortcut link to the folder using

`ln -s` or create and `Alias` to the shortcut in your webserver's configuration file .